# Can merchants tell the difference between a secured or unsecured credit card?

Tags: secured-credit-card

When I'm new in a country, the only credit card I can get might be a secured credit card.  I would need a credit card because I want to be able to rent cars.  Does it make any difference whatsoever whether this credit card is secured or regular?

A secured credit card is arguably not really a credit card as I'm not borrowing any money, so I wonder if car rental companies can tell and may be reluctant to rent to customers using secured credit cards, just as they are [unwilling to accept debit cards](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/55156/9083).  Can there possibly be a difference, directly or indirectly?

See also: *[Can merchants tell the difference between a credit card and embossed debit card?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27439/can-merchants-tell-the-difference-between-a-credit-card-and-embossed-debit-card)*

**NB:** I am *not* talking about prepaid cards.  I am talking about secured credit cards.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this a [secured credit card](http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/top-credit-cards/nerdwallets-best-secured-credit-cards/) or a [prepaid card](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/prepaid-cards-what-you-should-know/)?  A secure card _is_ a real credit card, and you _are_ borrowing money (although you also deposit money with them, separately).

Comment: I mean a real credit card.  Whether I am borrowing money is a matter of interpretation, as I cannot borrow any more than I have deposited.

Comment: If it was issued by the former Juniper Bank, I would recognize it as likely to be a secured card, personally.  There may be other brands that are similarly known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should not be able to tell the difference between a regular card and a secured card. The issue for a vendor is can they put a lock on the account equal to the transaction you are about to do. For a rental car company they don't have an exact idea of what your charges will be: it is based on many options some of which you don't decide until the day you return the car.

Because a secured card generally is on the small end (max measured in hundreds or at most $1,000) they might not be able to put a lock of sufficient size on the card.

Comment: Actually they can if they really wanted to. They can look up the BIN number.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on if you're talking [Secured credit card](http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/top-credit-cards/nerdwallets-best-secured-credit-cards/), or [prepaid debit card](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/prepaid-cards-what-you-should-know/).

There is no separate category for *secured* credit cards in the [IIN list](https://github.com/binlist/binlist-data/blob/master/iin-user-contributions.csv); however, it is possible some of them are classified as *debit* cards (despite not being debit cards).  You may want to check with the issuer to verify this (and you can check the IIN, or the first 6 digits of the card number, in the list I link to above to verify).  However, *prepaid debit cards* are debit cards, and are less likely to be accepted for travel, rental car, hotel, etc. types of charges (where a hold, similar to a deposit, is charged to the account).

This is one of the major differences between a *prepaid* card, such as the kind you top up at the grocer, and a *secured credit card*, where you deposit some money but separately pay back the amount you charge on the card (as a regular card). Secured cards are classified as credit cards, while prepaid cards are debit cards.

As mhoran notes, it's possible your credit limit could be too low to allow a hotel, airline, or rental agency to allow a transaction, but otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: I am talking about a Secured credit card.  I am not talking about a prepaid debit card (or any kind of debit card).